# How to run POJO test in Android Studio with test bindings?

Tags: android, unit-testing, intellij-idea, android-studio, pojo

With IntelliJ, I could create a directory "test", add some POJO test files and run them through the IDE.

With Android Studio, I can't find a way to do that. I tried to modify the build.gradle, but I always get the class not found exception.

The next step would be to set up a rule that loads some Guice bindings only during test.

My project looks like:

```
Project
  Module
  LibraryModule
    src
      main
        java/com/temp/...

      test
        java/com/temp/TestClass.java
```

TestClass.java:

```
package com.temp;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;


public class TestClass {

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {

    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        //do something
    }

}
```

build.gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    unitTest {
        java.srcDir file('src/test/java')
        resources.srcDir file('src/test/resources')
    }
}

dependencies {
    instrumentTestCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs/test', include: '*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
}
```

Error I get:

```
Class not found: "com.temp.TestClass"
```

When I run the same project in IntelliJ, I don't get any error. Any tips would help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete answer (based on what I found here: http://tryge.com/2013/02/28/android-gradle-build/)

build.gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    unitTest {
        java.srcDir file('src/test/java')
        resources.srcDir file('src/test/resources')
    }
}

configurations {
    unitTestCompile.extendsFrom runtime
    unitTestRuntime.extendsFrom unitTestCompile
}

dependencies {
    unitTestCompile files("$project.buildDir/classes/release")
}

task unitTest(type: Test, dependsOn: assemble) {
    description = "run unit tests"
    testClassesDir = project.sourceSets.unitTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = project.sourceSets.unitTest.runtimeClasspath
}

check.dependsOn unitTest


dependencies {
    unitTestCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs/test', include: '*.jar')
    unitTestCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar') // redundant, but don't know how to fix it

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
}
```

Then, to add the test bindings for Guice, make your test class extends that:

```
public class PojoTestCase {
    public PojoTestCase() {
        Guice.createInjector(new TestBindings()).injectMembers(this);
    }
}
```

And the way to run:

```
./gradlew unitTest
```

Also, the test won't run from Android Studio, but I'm fine with that for now.